# Unknown process using 50% of HDD periodically and slows down PC heavily

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

The PC is new, i3-3220 and with Windows 8 x64. Sometimes (couple days cycle) it starts crashing and slowing down instantly for no reason for like couple minutes. All programs stops, music stops playing, even mouse arrow lags heavily, I basically cannot do nothing until that unknown process ends.

And no, it is not a virus, I scanned it ten times, I have firewall and etc.

There's the screenshot, but I need more infos on what and why and how to stop it (just look at the Disk column):

[image: 1]

Comment: I would check out your hard drive's performance with S.M.A.R.T tools.

Comment: Please send a screenshot with **Resource Monitor**. That tool ties disk activity to individual processes. Task Monitor ties activity to applications.

Comment: This time I managed to catche pagefile.sys using most of the HDD and crashing the PC, but shouldn't it run when PC is on idle or something?

Comment: Maybe the dynamic pagefile size causes this behaviour?! You can try to set a static size for the pagefile instead of min/max value.